# adaOf encodes Lovelace/Ada ratio in phantom type

Tags: plutus, ada

`adaOf` encodes Lovelace/Ada ratio in [phantom type `Micro`](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/12099239d5bae033c914387257cb8d2c268838b3/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Ada.hs#L100)

```
adaOf :: Micro -> Ada
type Micro = Fixed E6
newtype Fixed (a :: k) = MkFixed Integer
```

Question: Being that the ratio is already encoded in the type, can I somehow get it, such that I can have a function that takes actual `Ada` token quantity -- not `Lovelace` quantity -- and gives back `Ada`, **without** hardcoding?

```
f :: Integer -> Ada
f adaQty = Lovelace (1_000_000 * n) -- don't really want to do this
```

I actually found [the constant](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/cc953b36ec9681cc28edf1accf08f48a31238e69/marlowe-playground-server/contracts/Swap.hs#L15) in the `plutus` repo:

```
lovelacePerAda = Constant 1000000
```

Comment: That constant you found probably isn't the one to use, since it's in the Marlowe libraries. Why are you interested in denominating in major units in your Plutus code? I could see the need in your UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `adaOf`

In a GHCi session with `plutus-ledger-api` in scope:

```
> import Plutus.V1.Ledger.Ada
> adaOf 1
Lovelace {getLovelace = 1000000}
```

Comment: Great! So that constant I found in Marlowe appears to be a mistake, because it is introducing a second source-of-truth.